Open in-app notification settings from inside the app

android.provider.Settings on docs
Is there anyway to open "In-app notification settings" from within my app? Currently I open the app's details page and then I have to click manually:
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + "com.google.android.projection.gearhead")));

ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS is for notifications which is a different subpage.
One thing I noticed is that the in-app notification settings appear in different places! For example, Android auto has it on the main details page, but facebook messenger has itr under Notifications subpage.
Any help would be appreciated.

TL:DR;
The main app page (e.g. Android Auto in your example) shows that entry when there's an activity in your app that has an <intent-filter> like
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
</intent-filter>

The app notifications settings page (e.g. Facebook Messenger) shows that entry when there's an activity in your app that has an <intent-filter> like:
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
</intent-filter>

Full answer:
Searching for "Additional settings in the app" on cs.android.com, I found this resource file for the Settings app: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Settings/res/values/strings.xml?q=%22Additional%20settings%20in%20the%20app%22.
Then, looking at where the app_settings_link string is used, you can find it in:

the main app settings page: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/app_info_settings.xml?q=app_settings_link)
the app notification settings page: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/app_notification_settings.xml

The logic for populating these settings can for each page is:

main: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/applications/appinfo/AppSettingPreferenceController.java;l=53-69
notifications: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/notification/app/AppLinkPreferenceController.java;l=32?q=app_link&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain and https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/notification/app/NotificationSettings.java?q=%22settingsIntent%20%3D%22&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain


Right, but the question was how can I open it via code, not how it's done or how I can make my app have that in-app notifications subpage. But I guess it's just not possible.

Do you want to open another app's settings page? If so, you could query for the same intents the way Settings does and use startActivity with that intent. https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring may affect how well that would work (since Settings is a system app, it has special privileges).
